# Whats the difference between a full screen form and a video game?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

If I create a form on visual studio c++, and make the form to be as big as the screen, and be over everything, I can create a form that will be in full screen. If I press the windows key, the startup menu shows up, and I can have any other programs running on top of mine.

If I run a video game such us league of legends, the screen glitches and the game goes on full screen. Nothing happens if you press windows key. You can't have anything on top of the game, and its like if it was on its own environment.

It's not that I seek for a complete answer or the code for doing it. It's just that I am curious to know what different techniques do game designers use.

Comment: +1 for including League of Legends in a StackOverflow question. Love that game. @Mario's answer is a good one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both techniques are essentially *fullscreen*, but there's one minor difference:

- The "real" fullscreen mode utilized by most games is called *exclusive fullscreen*, which grants the game (or program in general) exclusive control over the graphics output, so it's able to control things such as resolution, refresh rate, vertical synchronization, etc.
- The fullscreen window you created yourself, is a *cooperative fullscreen* (often referred to as *borderless window*), which still allows other programs to overlap your window. Things such as resolution, refresh rate, etc. are still handled by the overlaying windowing system.

Both techniques are available in many modern games, like *League of Legends* as well.

Your actual Windows key being blocked, however, is something different. The actual fullscreen mode doesn't have any influence on that. Instead, the program has to "eat" the key press event sent by the windowing system. If it's passed on, then it's still handled by the system (the way your program works). If it's getting eaten (i.e. not returned), then you'll get the behavior you see for *League of Legends*.